# Unable to compile after upgrade from crystal 0.19.4 to 0.20

Tags: crystal-lang, kemal

The shards install went well but compilation gave this error. 
Checked with [icr](https://github.com/greyblake/crystal-icr.git) that able to connect to local postgres database successfully. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
      [aranin@acbc328b9a5b:kemal-react-pg-chat-master]$ crystal build src/app.cr --release
  Error in src/app.cr:44: instantiating 'Kemal:Module#run()'

  Kemal.run
        ^~~

  in lib/kemal/src/kemal.cr:11: instantiating 'run(Nil)'

    def self.run(port = nil)
    ^

  in lib/kemal/src/kemal.cr:41: instantiating 'HTTP::Server::Context#params()'

          image = env.params.url["image"]
                      ^~~~~~

  in lib/kemal/src/kemal/context.cr:11: instantiating 'route_lookup()'

        @request.url_params ||= route_lookup.params
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~

  in lib/kemal/src/kemal/context.cr:21: instantiating 'HTTP::Request#override_method()'

        Kemal::RouteHandler::INSTANCE.lookup_route(@request.override_method.as(String), @request.path)
                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  in lib/kemal/src/kemal/request.cr:7: instantiating 'check_for_method_override!()'

      @override_method ||= check_for_method_override!
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  in lib/kemal/src/kemal/request.cr:14: instantiating 'Kemal::ParamParser#body()'

        params = Kemal::ParamParser.new(self).body
                                              ^~~~

  in lib/kemal/src/kemal/param_parser.cr:24: expanding macro

      {% for method in %w(url query body json) %}
      ^

  in macro 'macro_4590134368' /Users/aranin/Documents/rub-me/crystalax/kemal-react-pg-chat-master/lib/kemal/src/kemal/param_parser.cr:24, line 26:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably means that a version of kemal that targets Crystal 0.20.0 wasn't released yet. You can change your shard.yml file to point to the master branch:

```
dependencies:
  kemal:
    github: sdogruyol/kemal
    branch: master
```

That worked for me.

Comment: That worked!! Should have guessed myself...thanks a lot sir..most honored to have got response from you!!

Answer (score 1):

Kemal 0.17.0 released with Crystal 0.20.0 support. If you don't want to track master you can use it with

```
dependencies:
  kemal:
    github: sdogruyol/kemal
    version: 0.17.0
```